How do I add Listbox as a panedWindow Tkinter GUI?
Can someone show me how I can add a listbox to panedWindow?
Take this code for example: can the left-hand window be made into a listbox?
from tkinter import *

m1 = PanedWindow()
m1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

left = Entry(m1, bd=5)
m1.add(left)

m2 = PanedWindow(m1, orient=VERTICAL)
m1.add(m2)

top = Scale( m2, orient=HORIZONTAL)
m2.add(top)

bottom = Button(m2, text="OK")
m2.add(bottom)

mainloop()


Did you try just changing Entry to Listbox?

Did you try just changing Entry to Listbox? –
acw1668
23 mins ago, #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~yes i tried that

Then what is the problem actually?

ill try to get the actual code up

trying to put code up but getting#~~~~~~~~~~~
Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Do you want to add listbox?

Your code is working.

Do you want to have both Entry and Listbox widgets inside the left window?

I will try again to get the code up later, this is only a small section.

Thanks for the help, I’ll have a look when I’m back from work.


Can someone show me how I can add a listbox to "paneWindow"?

Take this code as an example: can the left-hand window be made into a
listbox?


The problem can be fixed.
Don't use a wildcard. Use this import tkinter as tk. Then use tk. prefix.
I added some colors. So you can see panedWindow adjustment.

Add StringVar()
Add Listbox widget.

The red color is the Entry widget
The green color is the Listbox.
The aqua color is the Scale widget.
The orange color is the Button widget
You're ready to go.
Snippet re-modified.
import tkinter as tk

mainWindow = tk.Tk()

mainWindow.title("PanedWindow Example")
mainWindow.geometry('350x200')

variable_string = tk.StringVar()
variable_string.set('This is left Entry')

m1 = tk.PanedWindow(mainWindow, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
m1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

label = tk.Entry(m1, textvariable=variable_string, bg="red", bd=5)
m1.add(label, stretch="always")

lstbox = tk.Listbox(m1,  bg="green")
m1.add(lstbox, stretch="always")

m2 = tk.PanedWindow(m1, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
m1.add(m2, stretch="never")

topScale = tk.Scale(m2, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, bg='aqua')
m2.add(topScale)

bottom =  tk.Button(m2, text="OK", bg='orange')
m2.add(bottom)

mainWindow.mainloop()

Screenshot:


Thanks for the help toyata supra, seems as though i have to learn stack overflow before i can post any meaningful reply!
